How to add click event handler on an edge node of partition chart in amCharts V5
I'm using amCharts V5 in my angular project.
I use partition chart as a kind of a filter. So that when one clicks on edge node (the last node that does not have any children) I will draw another chart underneath.
My problem at this moment is to make click working. There is no explicit example in docs but I assumed that this should work
series.nodes.template.events.on("click", function (event) {
        console.log("Clicked on node:", event);
      });

and here's how I create my series
      let series = container.children.push(
        am5hierarchy.Partition.new(root, {
          singleBranchOnly: false,
          orientation: this.chartData.orientation,
          downDepth: 1,
          initialDepth: 2,
          valueField: 'value',
          categoryField: 'name',
          childDataField: 'children',
          interactive: true,
          cursorOverStyle: "pointer",
          exportable: true,
          interactiveChildren: true
        })
      );

I don't even find anything in docs saying that it's not possible. Please someone help me solve this issue.
